# nf_reset() what does it this function do?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver

while trying to write a Linux kernel module for my project,i came across these functions. Can any one tell me what they do when called?. If you can quote some resources  which i could use so i could make less trouble to you guys. I searched for these methods them but only found header files. functions are given below

```
nf_reset()
skb_set_queue_mapping(skb, 0);
skb_dst_drop(skb);
skb_reset_network_header(skb);
skb_dst_drop(skb);
```

Comment: nf_reset is related to filtering. It allows you to

Comment: nf_reset is related to filtering. It allows you to reset port forwarding and ip-rerouting. Look into netfilter and you will see why resetting was necessary. A patch to the linux kernel was added in 2004 with the function nf_reset to reset netfilter related skb-fields
http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-hacking-HOWTO-3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nf_reset](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/skbuff.h?v=3.8#L2579), as it expected, resets NF states:

```
2579 static inline void nf_reset(struct sk_buff *skb)
2580 {
2581 #if defined(CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK) || defined(CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_MODULE)
2582         nf_conntrack_put(skb->nfct);
2583         skb->nfct = NULL;
2584 #endif
2585 #ifdef NET_SKBUFF_NF_DEFRAG_NEEDED
2586         nf_conntrack_put_reasm(skb->nfct_reasm);
2587         skb->nfct_reasm = NULL;
2588 #endif
2589 #ifdef CONFIG_BRIDGE_NETFILTER
2590         nf_bridge_put(skb->nf_bridge);
2591         skb->nf_bridge = NULL;
2592 #endif
2593 }
```